# Conditionally set a header inside an Angular Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am writing an interceptor which I want to conditionally set the authorization header.  I thought about doing this from the client:

```
const httpOptions = {sendAuthToken: false}
this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
```

However I can't find a way to get the options inside the interceptor. Only thing I can really get is the headers.  Perhaps I can set a header such as "UseAuthToken" on the request and then inside the interceptor delete "UseAuthToken" and set the Authorization Header based on the value of "UseAuthToken".  This seems hacky.

Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps I can set a header such as "UseAuthToken" on the request and then inside the interceptor delete "UseAuthToken" and set the Authorization Header based on the value of "UseAuthToken". This seems hacky.

You are *very* close.

If you're using JWT as an example, then set the `Bearer` but use a token *name* for which service is the *target*.

```
Authorization: Bearer <serviceA>
```

So that the interceptor will look for `Authorization` headers, and then replace `<serviceA>` with a JWT token for that *specific service*.

This has the advantage that the interceptor will allow other *bearer* headers to pass through unmodified, but also support multiple JWT tokens. You can search and replace `<serviceA>`, `<serviceB>` and so on.

Comment: I guess I'm not following you.  When you say "Bearer <serviceA>.  How do I get "serviceA" into the interceptor? I will eventually have quite a few services.  How in the service am I setting the specific token which will be picked up by the interceptor.  Do you happen to have an example?

Comment: I'm not following you either .. Can you add an example ?